# Creating a pull down menu with folders in NUKE python

Tags: python, nuke

I am trying to create a pull down in NUKE to list all the folders in a path. Here is my code so far:

```
p = nuke.Panel('my custom panel')
p.addEnumerationPulldown('my choices', (os.walk('E:').next()[1]))
ret = p.show()
```

A problem I have is if I have a folder name with spaces in it, it shows up as different choices..
For example the folder `System Test` shows up as two choices `System` and `Test`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The nuke.Panel enumeration pulldown cannot handle strings in the values.  You would have to replace any spaces with another character(s) and then create the pulldown.

```
p = nuke.Panel('my custom panel')
paths = [i.replace(" ", "-_-") for i in os.walk('E:').next()[1]]
p.addEnumerationPulldown('my choices', paths)
ret = p.show()
```

Ultimately, it's probably better to use a PythonPanel instead if it can fit your needs. It can handle spaces in an Enumeration_Knob attached to the panel.

```
import os
import nuke
import nukescripts

p = nukescripts.PythonPanel("foo")
k = nuke.Enumeration_Knob("bar", 'bar', os.walk('E:').next()[1])
p.addKnob(k) 
p.show()
```